# Change button color when disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I use the following button and when isDisabled is true the button is transparent
(here its always true for the example but in my program its bound to command...)
what I want is that when the button is disabled the color remain the same just ligther,
how can I achive that?

```
    <Button  
                             Width="100"
                             Height="25"
                             Background="#f0ab00"
                             Content="Run"
                             FontSize="16"
                             Foreground="#ffffff"
                             IsDefault="True"
                             Margin="10,0,20,0"
                             IsEnabled="false" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Take a look at Styles and Triggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to edit or make a ControlTemplate for the Button. (use a key to bind the controltemplate to the button).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonBaseControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Control:

```
        <Button  
                         Width="100"
                         Height="25"
                         Background="#f0ab00"
                         Content="Run"
                         FontSize="16"
                         Foreground="#ffffff"

                         IsDefault="True"
                         Margin="10,0,20,0"
                         IsEnabled="false" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonBaseControlTemplate1}"  />
```

Comment: How would you do it? just adding a style with the triggers doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f0ab00"/>        
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f0aa00"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can play with the colors .

Comment: `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>` doesn't seem to be a good idea, when the trigger activates upon `IsEnabled` gets set to false...

Comment: It's supposed to do that. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: This answer is correct. I think that Herdo is asking why you included line 4. From my point of view line 4 is not needed, but also isn't a problem to have either. It just means the style starts out enabled, which I thought was the default anyway.

Comment: Yes it doesn't do anything is default anyway, just for illustration. I removed that line.